# Обособление приложений

Tags: пунктуация

Как лучше обособить данное приложение, запятыми или дефисом?

...на котором жена преследовала меня велосипедиста по шоссе и лесным тропам...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, можно или запятыми, или тире. Запятыми обособляется слово "велосипедиста" с двух сторон, поэтому двусмысленности не возникает, тем более что интонации перечисления здесь нет. Если же Вы опасаетесь этого двойного смысла, то можно с двух сторон поставить тире

Comment: Нет, здесь возможности воспринять как перечисление нету. Но главное, что дефис здесь, по-видимому, вряд ли подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Приложение относится к личному местоимению, поэтому нужна запятая.

Answer (score 0):

А я бы чисто из желания похулиганить поставил дефис. И фраза к этому (к хулиганству) располагает... ))

Comment: Фраза там... вообще... Но от подобного хулиганства лучше воздержусь. :)